# Inconsistent MapperParsingException on ElasticSearch 2.4.1

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I'm doing dynamic mapping for the indices and found that one consistently works while the other one doesn't even though they are basically the same.

```
MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[mapper [$source.attributes.th.values.display] of different type, current_type [string], merged_type [double]];
```

This one works

```
{
    "_id": "581b883cfb54c66569adfc6c",
    "$source": {
        "attributes": {
            "th": [
                {
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "display": "13.726133,100.5731003",
                            "value": "13.726133,100.5731003"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_v": 4,
                    "type": "geo",
                    "_dt": "com.7leaf.framework.Attribute",
                    "slug": "lat-long",
                    "key": "Lat / Long"
                },
                {
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "display": 34,
                            "value": 34
                        }
                    ],
                    "_v": 4,
                    "type": "number",
                    "_dt": "com.7leaf.framework.Attribute",
                    "slug": "number-of-floors",
                    "key": "จำนวนชั้น"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't

```
{
    "_id": "5824bce9fb54c611b092eec6",
    "$source": {
        "attributes": {
            "th": [
                {
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "display": "13.726133,100.5731003",
                            "value": "13.726133,100.5731003"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "geo",
                    "_dt": "com.7leaf.framework.Attribute",
                    "_v": 4,
                    "slug": "lat-long",
                    "key": "Lat / Long"
                },
                {
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "display": 34,
                            "value": 34
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "number",
                    "_dt": "com.7leaf.framework.Attribute",
                    "_v": 4,
                    "slug": "number-of-floors",
                    "key": "จำนวนชั้น"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What could have possibly gone wrong? The "display" and "value" field can be of any type. I just don't get how it works for the first index and not the second. It doesn't make much sense. Any pointer is appreciated.

This is what the mapping looks like for the one that worked. It's automatically generated.

```
"values": {
  "properties": {
    "display": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "english": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        },
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "value": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "english": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        },
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For those who didn't believe the first one actually worked. Here's the screenshot. I have a lot of documents in that index.

[image]

Here's the Java code I use for bulk reindexing. Nothing special really.

```
public BulkResponse bulkIndex(List<JSONObject> entries){
    if(client == null) return null;
    
    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
    
    for(JSONObject document : entries){
        String indexName = getIndexName(
                document.getString(Constants.DATABASE), document.getString(Constants.COLLECTION));
        
        String id = document.getString(Constants.ID + "@$oid");
        
        bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex(
                indexName, document.getString(Constants.COLLECTION), id)
                .setSource(document.toMap()));
    }
    
    return bulkRequest.get();
}
```

Here's the stacktrace from ElasticSearch:

```
MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[mapper [$source.attributes.th.values.display] of different type, current_type [string], merged_type [double]];
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:156)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:309)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndex(IndexShard.java:580)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndexOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.prepareIndexOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:211)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:223)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardIndexOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:327)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:120)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:657)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:287)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:279)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mapper [$source.attributes.th.values.display] of different type, current_type [string], merged_type [double]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.doMerge(FieldMapper.java:378)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper.doMerge(StringFieldMapper.java:382)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.merge(FieldMapper.java:364)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.merge(FieldMapper.java:53)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.doMerge(ObjectMapper.java:528)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.merge(ObjectMapper.java:501)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.merge(ObjectMapper.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.doMerge(ObjectMapper.java:528)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.merge(ObjectMapper.java:501)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.merge(ObjectMapper.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.doMerge(ObjectMapper.java:528)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.merge(ObjectMapper.java:501)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:271)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:308)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseAndMergeUpdate(DocumentParser.java:740)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:354)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:254)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:308)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:328)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObject(DocumentParser.java:254)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:124)
    ... 18 more
```

---

### Workaround

I added the mapping I mentioned above as part of default template and I was able to get around it. However, I have no idea why it works. I can now store any kind of properties in the same field.

```
{
  "template": "*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type":  "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                },
                "english": {
                  "type":  "string",
                  "analyzer": "english"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
          "$source": {
            "properties": {
              "attributes": {
                "properties": {
                  "en": {
                    "properties": {
                      "values": {
                        "properties": {
                          "display": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "fields": {
                              "english": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "english"
                              },
                              "raw": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          "value": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "fields": {
                              "english": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "english"
                              },
                              "raw": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "th": {
                    "properties": {
                      "values": {
                        "properties": {
                          "display": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "fields": {
                              "english": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "english"
                              },
                              "raw": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          "value": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "fields": {
                              "english": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "english"
                              },
                              "raw": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Any pointer on how to make it dynamic so I don't need to specify it for every language? In the example above, it's working for English (en) and Thai (th) and I'm planning to support 40+ languages and I don't want to have to add more mapping for each language.

Comment: Why don't you have `_source` in the second document?

Comment: Copy and paste error. Sorry, They are literally the same. It's actually a much larger document. One I copied from Kibana Sense and they other I had to print it out before sending to ElasticSearch since it always failing.

Comment: Even the first document doesn't save. This is because one `display` is a string and the other is a number. That cannot work. You need both to have the same type. The only way the first document saves is if the `th` array only contains a single element.

Comment: Trust me the first one saved. I'm attaching a screenshot from Kibana Sense so you can see it. There are over 100 objects inside the array and some of them are string, integer, double, boolean and even geo-point..

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: 2.4.1 as mentioned in the subject of the question.

Comment: Doh! Sorry too early :-) How did you create the first document?

Comment: Exactly the same way as the first one through Java client. The documents are slightly different, but the part that doesn't work are exactly the same.

Comment: Puzzling. Even when I take the first document and try to index it via curl, it fails.

Comment: What's the most confusing thing is that I tried reindexing the collection that worked and then only 2 out of 6 were reindexed without an issue. Then I tried again the second time and got the same results. Then I tried again for the 3rd time and all 6 got indexed properly. This is without any code change. I'm lost for word at this point. At least the index that doesn't work consistently doesn't work.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how your Java code looks like and eventually the full stack traces you get when you go through the process you just described. Usually, when a mapping exception occurs, the document doesn't get saved at all. Are you indexing the document in several pieces/steps by any chance?

Comment: No. It's just one single document at a time. I will add some Java code to the details.

Comment: Any chance to see some stack traces?

Comment: Just added stacktrace from ElasticSearch.

Comment: It matters which of your documents created the index first! If the first document that got into the index is a "correct" one where there is no confusion between the types of the same field, then the index gets created with let's say a `string` field for `display`. Then you can very well index the "problematic" without issues. Index the documents one by one in a **non-existent index** (so that it's automatically created) and see the difference in behavior. I really doubt that your bulk indexing code is inserting one document at a time.

Comment: If you want to send a bulk of documents, you can't tell which actually will trigger the creation of the index. Some documents will be sent to one shard, some to another and so on. There will be a mix of messages from the shards to the master node with the mapping and the first one that "wins" can be the "wrong" one or the "correct" one. You need a dynamic mapping template to control this, as you tested already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matters which of your documents created the index first! If the first document that got into the index is a "correct" one where there is no confusion between the types of the same field, then the index gets created with let's say a string field for display. Then you can very well index the "problematic" without issues. Index the documents one by one in a non-existent index (so that it's automatically created) and see the difference in behavior. I really doubt that your bulk indexing code is inserting one document at a time.

If you want to send a bulk of documents, you can't tell which actually will trigger the creation of the index. Some documents will be sent to one shard, some to another and so on. There will be a mix of messages from the shards to the master node with the mapping and the first one that "wins" can be the "wrong" one or the "correct" one. You need a dynamic mapping template to control this, as you tested already.

My suggestion is to use a more targeted template, that uses wildcards to cover for all the languages you have. If what is different for your languages is just the name of one of the fields - `th` or `en` etc - then use `path_match` and then the template that you have but in a more concise way without duplicating the same mapping over and over:

```
PUT /_template/language_control
{
  "template": "language_control*",
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "display_values": {
            "path_match": "$source.attributes.*.values.*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                "english": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "english"
                },
                "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you look at `path_match` that will cover `$source.attributes.th.values.display`, `$source.attributes.en.values.display` and also the other values from the languages like `$source.attributes.th.values.value`, `$source.attributes.en.values.value`.

Comment: This works well since at least I'm able to index the data. However, it has a very odd behavior only for double. Integer and boolean are still returned as integer and boolean when queried while double becomes string. I still haven't been able to get an answer from ElasticSearch team about this. It would be nice if things work consistently.

Comment: Glad this worked out for you! Andrei should be able to nudge a few people internally to get some insights, right Andrei? ;-)

Comment: Still trying to understand the issue... The template I provided should catch any field types, it shouldn't matter if it's numeric, string or boolean. But then you say _are still returned as integer and boolean when queried_ so is this something at query time?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is to augment your dynamic templates for all types to be mapped to strings, since you probably won't query on them.

It basically boils down to modifying your template to the one below, which will work with the documents you've shown above. Note that I've only added a dynamic mapping for the `long` type, but you can add a similar mapping for other types as well. The bottom line being to make sure that the mapper won't find any ambiguities when indexing your documents.

```
{
  "template": "*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                },
                "english": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "english"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "longs": {
            "match_mapping_type": "long",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that I've never been able to index the first document, which always fails for me. As @Andrei rightly said, when indexing documents in bulk you have no guarantee which document is indexed first into which shard and thus you have no guarantee of which field will "win", i.e. will be first indexed and sets the field type.

Comment: Why do I need to do this mapping for long and other types? If the fields are specified as string, shouldn't that already take care of all cases? These are fields that are for storage and not for querying anyway. Although, I still do see from time-to-time that some documents are still failing to index, but bulk reindexing always fixes the problem somehow.

Comment: Because e.g. `"display": 34` is not a string, but a long. However, if you index those longs as strings, then you'll be fine.

Comment: Based on Andrei suggestion, I was able to get data to index, but there are still inconsistency as I mentioned in the comment above.